# Short story about a teenage boy living in a mining colony, who is given an AI friend by his parents

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for the name of the story about a teenage boy who is living on a mining colony (vague recollection says on a moon, but not necessarily the Moon).

He apparently has some form of severe social anxiety, as he never wants to spend any time around the other kids. He actively seeks time alone. His parents get him an AI friend - I believe it was housed in a wearable forearm device like a large wristwatch. It had to be implanted as well, as the AI is able to communicate with the boy without having to speak aloud; I want to say it was plugged into his brain in some fashion so that the two can talk directly mind-to-mind, as it were.

The story ends with a trial-by-fire type of rite-of-passage all the other children do once they reach a certain age. It has to do with getting some equipment to work properly out in the vacuum of the surface.

I don't know when it was published, but I feel like I read it in the late 90's or earliest years of the 2000's.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? I've been thinking a lot about this story for a while, and searched everywhere I can think of to find it again. Any help finding it again would be greatly appreciated.